# Can Onsite PaymentGateway Support Notification

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have seen many implementations of **notification** in **OffsitePaymentGatewayBase** Like **WorldPay**, **QuickPay**

Can I Extend the OnsitePaymentGatewayBase class and use **onNotify()** Method for receiving **Payment** **notification**?

Comment: Follow the docs, [On-site payment gateways](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/create-payment-gateway/on-site-gateways).

Comment: The docs only mentions that method in the [off-site payment gateways](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/create-payment-gateway/off-site-gateways) docs.

Comment: @NoSssweat Docs is incomplete , its mentioned as a link but the link is broken. I have raised this question in slack for drupal-commerce and they have replied well

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this question to slack for drupal commerce and they responded.
the Response is below

**Slack Answer:**
*your payment gateway must implement* https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/payment/src/Plugin/Commerce/PaymentGateway/SupportsNotificationsInterface.php
*the interface for offsite payment gateway is already extending that. that's why it's available for every offsite gateway, but needs to be added explicitly for onsites*